# LUKS: speed up decryption

Tags: luks

`/dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0` is a LUKS device backed on `/dev/sdc3`:

```
$ sudo pv /dev/sdc3 >/dev/null
[ 503MiB/s]

$ sudo pv /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0  >/dev/null
[72.0MiB/s]
```

The encrypted device is thus waaay slower than the raw device. Why?

`top` says:

```
top - 20:07:52 up 9 min,  2 users,  load average: 2.03, 1.42, 0.83
Tasks: 604 total,   3 running, 601 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  3.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.1 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :    472.4 total,    397.7 free,      0.9 used,     73.8 buff/cache
GiB Swap:      8.0 total,      8.0 free,      0.0 used.    469.3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                        
   4845 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  81.2   0.0   0:21.96 kworker/u101:2+kcryptd/253:0                   
   4846 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  81.2   0.0   0:16.22 kworker/u101:4+kcryptd/253:0                   
   4844 root      20   0    5640   2200   1960 D  13.8   0.0   0:08.04 pv                                             
   4725 tange     20   0    9912   4624   3220 R   1.0   0.0   0:06.55 top
```

So it could be due to only 2 `kcryptd` decrypting. The system has 48 cores.

If the performance is limited by these 2 `kcryptd`, how can I use more of the 48 cores to do the work and get my 500 MB/s?

Thinking this may be a single-thread issue I tested:

```
parallel --recend '' --pipepart -a /dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0 --block -1 'cat >/dev/null'
```

and that gives the full 500 MB/s and activates a lot more `kcryptd`s according to in `top`. That is great, because that means that LUKS *can* deliver the 500 MB/s.

Sequential writing is also fine (not 500 MB/s, but around 300 MB/s - possibly limited by SSD speed).

So the problem seems to be limited to sequential reading.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor : 47
vendor_id : AuthenticAMD
cpu family : 16
model    : 9
model name : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6174
stepping : 1
microcode : 0x10000d9
cpu MHz  : 2200.035
cache size : 512 KB
physical id  : 1
siblings : 12
core id  : 5
cpu cores : 12
apicid   : 27
initial apicid  : 27
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level  : 5
wp      : yes
flags    : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid amd_dcm pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt nodeid_msr hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
bugs    : tlb_mmatch fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips : 4400.20
TLB size : 1024 4K pages
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate

$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdc3
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          18
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           9498ddbe-9613-4ae3-8fb4-e65913d800c8
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
     offset: 16777216 [bytes]
     length: (whole device)
     cipher: aes-xts-plain64
     sector: 512 [bytes]

$ sudo cryptsetup benchmark
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1       260580 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256     717220 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512     565574 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160  403919 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool  262669 iterations per second for 256-bit key
argon2i       4 iterations, 256407 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
argon2id      4 iterations, 260616 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
#     Algorithm |       Key |      Encryption |      Decryption
        aes-cbc        128b        74.8 MiB/s       130.1 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        128b        47.6 MiB/s       144.4 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        128b       116.1 MiB/s       137.4 MiB/s
        aes-cbc        256b        33.5 MiB/s        68.5 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        256b        53.4 MiB/s       144.3 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        256b       125.7 MiB/s       150.8 MiB/s
        aes-xts        256b       130.3 MiB/s       132.6 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        256b       119.3 MiB/s       138.9 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        256b       135.4 MiB/s       144.2 MiB/s
        aes-xts        512b        99.0 MiB/s       102.7 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        512b       136.8 MiB/s       138.9 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        512b       144.9 MiB/s       144.3 MiB/s
```

Comment: does the system have aes acceleration? (`cat /proc/cpuinfo`)

Comment: ...and if yes, is the relevant module loaded by the time the crypt container is opened? easy way to check would be to open another one at runtime & compare speeds. for that matter, does it even use aes cipher or something else (`cryptsetup luksDump`, `cryptsetup benchmark`)?

Comment: @frostschutz Added output.

Comment: "Why does the physical device have 100% utilization when accessed through the LUKS'ed device?" -- That's not what that metric means. What that metric means is that 100% of wall time is being taken doing I/O operations, but this can be misleading: it could just be that way because the I/O operation takes longer for other reasons (poor I/O scheduling, device mapper shenanigans, etc). In general, I/O metrics when using DM in Linux are often either double counted, wrong, or specious even without DM. Use PSI instead. See here at 30:49 for more information: https://youtu.be/beefUhRH5lU?t=1849

Comment: So wild guess... it's CPU limited due to lack of aes acceleration, and pv/dd is a bad benchmark since there'll be only one thread per reader. May or may not be faster when involving multiple parallel readers.

Comment: could also switch from aes-xts-plain64 512bit (if you're using that) to 256bit for some speed gain but it requires re-encrypting everthing